# How do you configure s3cmd for Windows 10/Python 3.10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, s3cmd

I'm using Windows 10 and trying to find a way to access my private S3 repository.  I have GitBash and this version of Python

```
$ python --version
Python 3.10.5
```

I downloaded s3cmd v2.2 but when after running the set up process successfully, I get this error when i try and configure

```
$ python s3cmd --configure
      0 [main] python 1370 C:\Python310\python.exe: *** fatal error - Internal error: TP_NUM_C_BUFS too small: 50
   1731 [main] python 1370 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to python.exe.stackdump
```

Is there another way to access my private s3 repo or a way to fix s3cmd?

Comment: What about using a GUI client (e.g. [my] WinSCP?)

Comment: I thought WinSCP was only for FTP/SFTP.  How do you use it for S3 connections?

Comment: Just select S3 protocol on the [Login dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login).